# Comparing two different types of pointer

Tags: c, pointers, types, compare

In C programming, comparing two different types of pointers like this :

```
int i = 1;
double d = 2.5;

int *ip = &i;
double *dp = &d;

if(ip != dp) // is it UB?
    printf("Not same\n");
```

Is `ip != dp` undefined behaviour in C?

Comment: 1. Why not look up the standard yourself? 2. Why are you doing this?

Comment: Yes it took to me the whole 40 seconds to find. http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.9p2

Comment: @EugeneSh. So whats yr answer, UB, implementation defined, valid and always not equal?

Comment: Cited below: *both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types;*

Comment: still not clear what the answer is. Are you saying its UB to do this?

Comment: Yes, if I read it correctly.

Comment: This is a *constaint violation* in C language. I.e. the code you posted is invalid. It is not compilable as C. This is where the Standard's area of responsibility ends. Everything else is just quirks of your specific compiler.

Answer (score 7):

The direct comparison `ip != dp` is invalid in C. Specification of `!=` operator does not allow mixing `int *` and `double *` pointers in one comparison. It is a *constraint violation* in C (aka a "compile error"). A conforming C compiler will report your code as invalid by issuing a diagnostic message.

What happens next depends solely on your compiler. It has nothing to do with C language.

Referring to this code as "C code that produces undefined behavior" would be misleading. It is formally true, but it makes exactly as much sense as saying that the text of "War and Piece" is "C code that produces undefined behavior" (in some strange C compiler that accepts it).

The key point here is that this code language constraints meaning that it is not C code at all.

Comment: Some people argue that constraints are not part of "syntactic and semantic rules": they're not syntactic, and the standard consistently lists Constraints separately from Semantics.  In this case, 6.5.9/2 is a constraint, and 6.5.9/3 ff. are the semantics.  These people say that a diagnostic should be emitted, and the code should behave as specified by the rest of the standard.  In most cases this leads to UB by omission, but not this particular case where 6.3.2.3 (Pointer conversions) can apply

Comment: @M.M: True. I might have misused/misinterpreted the concept of "semantic rule" then. However, I don't see the relevance of 6.3.2.3 to this situation. 6.3 is not in any way intended to imply that these conversions *shall* apply whenever they *can* apply. Applicability of implicit conversions is defined/restricted by specification if individual operators in 6.5 (6.5.9 in this case). And I don't see anything in 6.5.9 that would allow implicit pointer conversion to take place in this context.

Answer (score 2):

This is **not** well defined.  A prerequisite of the `!=` operator is that if both operands are pointers, they must be to compatible types.  `int` and `double` are not compatible types.

From section 6.5.9 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> *2* One of the following shall hold:
>
> — both operands have arithmetic type;
>
> — **both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of
>   compatible types;**
>
> — one operand is a pointer to an object type and the other is a
>   pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of void; or
>
> — one operand is a pointer and the other is a null pointer constant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this operation is undefined, and Kernighan & Ritchie were mentioned about that in their book "The C Programming Language":

> Any pointer can be meaningfully compared for equality or inequality with zero. But the behavior is undefined for arithmetic or comparisons with pointers that do not point to members of the same array.

This means that pointers that points to different types cannot be checked for equality.

Comment: Does "points to different types cannot be checked for equality." apply to comparing `void *` against `char *`?  I suspect an exception in this case.

Comment: K&R is not the C Standard

Comment: M.M you are right, but my motivation was offering a reference to rsp for further reading.